# display and print elements from SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm stuck in an application , and I need your advice .

I wish the first page to be able to run items from the database using the buttons inainte(front) and inapoi(back), but I try to order the database in OnClick Lisiner , but the application crashes , and do not know why , tend to,  I think i don`t appelea ,the items in the database, properly.

How do you think I should do , or what should I do for this job to do , to run elements .

And again the problem that I have not found it anywhere, how do I do the print button ,to send the print information from the screen element displayed.

The vast majority of the code I've written was hith the help of tutorials.
So, this is the code, and files, that i creat:

Activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 android:orientation="vertical">


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImagineaRetetei"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/INAPOI"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numeleRetetei" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Carrefour Suceava"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
     />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Numele Retetei"
    android:id="@+id/numeleRetetei"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PPR"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PPR" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="99dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Adauga"
    android:id="@+id/ADD"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/PPR" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Printeaza"
    android:id="@+id/PPR"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/INAINTE" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Inapoi"
    android:id="@+id/INAPOI"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Inainte"
    android:id="@+id/INAINTE"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_main2.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabContactList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="458dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Retetele mele"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabCreator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Adauga Reteta"
                    android:id="@+id/lblCreatorTitle"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imgViewContactImage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/index" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:hint="Numele Retetei" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Adaugare"
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:enabled="false" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Inapoi"
                    android:id="@+id/btnRET"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:enabled="true" />

               </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
     </TabHost>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Contact.java

```
 package ciprian.retete_carrefour;

 import android.net.Uri;


 public class Contact {

   private String _name;
   private  Uri _imageURI;
   private  int _id;

   public Contact(int id, String name, Uri imageURI){

        _id = id;
        _name = name;
        _imageURI = imageURI;

  }
     public int getId()         {        return _id;          }

     public String getName()    {        return _name;        }

     public Uri getImageURI()   {        return _imageURI;    }

 }
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
package ciprian.retete_carrefour;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager",
      TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts",
      KEY_ID = "id",
      KEY_NAME = "name",
      KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";


  public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
  {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }



  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "( " + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT )");


   }

   @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    onCreate(db);
  }

 //CREARE DE USER

 public void createContact (Contact contact)
 {
   SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();

  }

  //CITIRE BAZA DE DATE

  public Contact getContact(int id)
  {
      SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

      Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_IMAGEURI}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();


    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(2)));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contact;

  }

//STERGERE CONTACT DIN DB

   public void deleteContact(Contact contact)    {
      SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
      db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
    db.close();
}


  public int getContactsCount()    {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return count;

 }


 public int updateContact(Contact contact)    {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
    db.close();
    return rowsAffected;

  }

public List<Contact> getAllContacts()    {
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())        {

        do {
              contacts.add(new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(2))));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contacts;
   }
```

}

Main2Activity.java

```
package ciprian.retete_carrefour;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

  private static final int DELETE=1;


  EditText nameTxt;
  ImageView contactImageImgView;
  List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
  ListView contactListView;
  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://ciprian.retete_carrefour/drawable/index.jpg");
  DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
  int longClickedItemIndex;
  ArrayAdapter<Contact> contactAdapter;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    contactImageImgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    registerForContextMenu(contactListView);
    contactListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            longClickedItemIndex = position;
            return false;
        }
    });

    tabHost.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("creator");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabCreator);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Adaugare");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Memorate");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


    final Button retBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRET);
    final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Contact contact = new Contact(dbHandler.getContactsCount(), String.valueOf(nameTxt.getText()), imageUri);
            if (!contactExists(contact)) {
                dbHandler.createContact(contact);
                Contacts.add(contact);
                contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(nameTxt.getText()) + " a fost adaugata la retete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(nameTxt.getText()) + " exista deja, te rugam alege alta reteta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    retBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

    nameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(nameTxt.getText()).trim().length() > 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    contactImageImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecteaza Imaginea Retetei"), 1);
        }
    });


    if (dbHandler.getContactsCount()!=0)
        Contacts.addAll(dbHandler.getAllContacts());


    populateList();

 }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Optiuni");
                    menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Sterge");

    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {

            case DELETE:
                    dbHandler.deleteContact(Contacts.get(longClickedItemIndex));
                    Contacts.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
                    contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


    private boolean contactExists(Contact contact)
    {
        String name = contact.getName();
        int contactCount = Contacts.size();

        for (int    i=0; i <contactCount; i++)
        {
            if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(Contacts.get(i).getName()) == 0)
                return true;
        }

        return false;

    }



    public void onActivityResult (int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (reqCode == 1) {
                imageUri = data.getData();
                contactImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
            }
        }

    }



  private void populateList() {
      contactAdapter = new ContactListAdapter();
      contactListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

  }

    private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>
    {
        public ContactListAdapter()
        {
            super(Main2Activity.this, R.layout.listview_item,Contacts);
        }




         @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
         {
             if (view == null)
                 view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

             Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

             TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
             name.setText(currentContact.getName());
             ImageView ivContactImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
                ivContactImage.setImageURI(currentContact.getImageURI());
             return view;
           }



      }


}
```

listview_item.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivContactImage" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Numele Retetei"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   package ciprian.retete_carrefour;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;

 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 //  DatabaseHandler bazaDate;
 //   Button inainte;
 //   List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   //    setupInainte();
       setupAdaugaProdus();
  }

 /*   private void setupInainte()
   {
    inainte = (Button)findViewById(R.id.INAINTE);
    inainte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Contacts = bazaDate.getAllContacts();
            int contactCount = Contacts.size();

            for (int    i=0; i <contactCount; i++)
            {

                Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(i);
                TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numeleRetetei);
                name.setText(currentContact.getName());
                ImageView ivContactImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImagineaRetetei);
                ivContactImage.setImageURI(currentContact.getImageURI());
            }

        }
    });



  }*/

  private  void setupAdaugaProdus()
  {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ADD);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
          }
       });
   }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ciprian.retete_carrefour">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please paste the crash logs if you want to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a NullPointerException probably because you haven't initialized the database helper class in your MainActivity.

Try:

```
DatabaseHandler bazaDate = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

Only then you may call the methods you have implemented such as GetAllContacts

Comment: Dosen`t work. It say`s dabasehandler(Context) in databasehandler() cannot be aplyed ... and if i pu 'DatabaseHandler bazaDate = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());' it crashe`s

Comment: Have you tried DatabaseHandler bazaDate = new DatabaseHandler(this);

Comment: with (this) works perfectly dialing DB . But the OnCliclisiner it`s not working propreli , it`s show`s onli the last element added to database

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: now i just have to figure out wath to do with the printer button, to print on paper, i was tanking, it my be something with the id of the elements, but i dont know

Comment: Check the length of your array from getAllContacts to make sure it is correct, and debug your method, should be easy. If the answer was helpful and solved your problem accept it as the right answer. Anything else, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try i!

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_IMAGEURI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
     values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Comment: the db works, i don`t know how to appel the info from the DB, and show them on main, in the imageview and textview....

Comment: you see tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/